# Symfony2 form theme override collection entry row with loop?

Tags: php, loops, symfony, types, twig

I have a problem with my form collection entries.

For example my form type.

```
// ProfileFormType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new EmailType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
        ))
    ;
}
```

Thats the email type for the collection above.

```
// EmailType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('publicAccess')
    ;
}
```

And now the form theme for that collection entry row.

```
{%- block _fos_user_profile_form_emails_entry_row %}
    <div class="email form-group{% if form.email.vars.errors | length %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-3">
            <span class="input-group-addon">{{ form_widget(form.publicAccess) }}</span>
            {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
            {#% if loop is defined %}{{ dump(loop) }}{% endif %#}
            <span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-xs"></span></a></span>
        </div>
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    </div>
{% endblock -%}
```

But the problem is that i have no loop or other things for the entries...

How can i check if the entry is the last entry of the collection?

The reason is that i want to add the "minus" button instead the "glypicon-plus" for all entries which not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the last entry with :

```
{% if loop.last %}
    {# your custom code for the last entry #}
{% else %}
    {# the others entries #}
{% endif %}
```

So you can use it to choose the good button :

```
{%- block _fos_user_profile_form_emails_entry_row %}
    <div class="email form-group{% if form.email.vars.errors | length %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-3">
            <span class="input-group-addon">{{ form_widget(form.publicAccess) }}</span>
            {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
            <span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon {{ (loop.last) ? 'glypicon-plus' : 'glyphicon-minus' }} glyphicon-xs"></span></a></span>
        </div>
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    </div>
{% endblock -%}
```

Comment: No sorry. `Variable "loop" does not exist` I think there is no loop in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should compare the entry with the parent's last element.

Like this:

```
{% if form == form.parent | last %}
    it's the last
{% else %}
    it's not the last
{% endif %}
```